# Remove one image from multiple input file

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, spring-mvc

I'm trying to work on updating pictures on server side and in that way I'm trying to show preview of that pictures before updating **(without using ajax)** to server side (Spring MVC).

The problem is that I can't remove only the picture that I want to remove. It remove the preview but the value still in the input file.

The `$(inputFileID).val('')` clear all the input file.

So is there any way to deal with that without using ajax ?

Here is my code :

```js
document.getElementById('fileButton').onclick = function() {
    document.getElementById('files').click();
};
$(document).ready(function() {
 var filesToUpload =[];
   if (window.File && window.FileList && window.FileReader) {
  
     $("#files").on("change", function(e) {
       var files = e.target.files,
            filesLength = files.length;
    
       for (var i = 0; i < filesLength; i++) {
         var f = files[i]
    
         filesToUpload.push(files[i].name);
        
         var fileReader = new FileReader();
         fileReader.onload = (function(e) {
           var file = e.target;
       
           $("<span class=\"pip\">" +
             "<img class=\"imageThumb\" id=\"image"+i+"\" src=\"" + e.target.result + "\" title=\"" + file.name + "\"/>" +
             "<br/><span id=\""+i+"\" class=\"remove\">X</span>" +
             "</span>").insertAfter("#files");
           
            $(".remove").click(function(){
            $(this).parent(".pip").remove();
            $("#files").val('');
       });
       });
         fileReader.readAsDataURL(f);
    
       }
     });
   } else {
     // 
   }
 });
```

```css
#files {
 display: none;
}

.imageThumb {
 max-height: 150px;
 border: 2px solid;
 padding: 1px;
 cursor: pointer;
}

.pip {
 display: inline-block;
 margin: 10px 10px 0 0;
}

.remove {
 font-family: Circular, -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, Roboto,
  Helvetica Neue, sans-serif !important;
 font-size: 18px !important;
 display: block;
 background: #444;
 border: 1px solid black;
 color: white;
 text-align: center;
 cursor: pointer;
}

.remove:hover {
 background: white;
 color: #000 !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="picturePreview" style="text-align: center;">
   <button class='btn pictureBtn' id="fileButton">AJOUTER DES
    PHOTOS</button>

   <div class="field" align="center">
    <input  type="file" id="files"
     name="files[]" multiple="multiple" accept="image/*" />
   </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Withou ajax, no. FileList can't be modified by scripts except to clear it. But there is no `<form>` in your code, so how do you post this? Also, why this *without AJAX* restriction?

Comment: It's just one part of my form. With AJAX I will have to alter a big part of mycode. But if there is no way to do it without AJAX so I have to use it.

Comment: Yes indeed there is no other way. (To do it with AJAX, you would convert the FileList to an Array of Files, filtering out the one you didn't wanted, before using  a FormData to hold all your form's values.)